# Jre is missing in Android SDK

Tags: java, android-studio

When I am trying to start the monitor in Android studio, I get an error as it's not able to find the `javaw.exe` in following location `C:\Users\sophiya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64`

I have already set the `JAVA_HOME` in env variables and added the same in `PATH` variable. I have also added the JDK location in Android studio. Still it's not working. Please suggest if any has idea where is the problem?

Comment: What is "the monitor in android studio"?

Comment: the monitor is inside C:\Users\sophiya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools.  It's used to monitr threads , heap of app min android studio.

Comment: how do you expect to run exe file on android? exe is for windows

Comment: I am trying to run it in windows only... because i am trying to monitor an android device performance by connecting to my windows system..

Comment: I have installed jdk in c:\Program Files\...\jre. But when i am trying to start monitor it's looking for jre in   C:\Users\sophiya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64. My question is why the android monitor is looking for jdk in this location and how i can resolve it?